# Availability Group failover stuck in Resolving State

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, windows-server

I am setting up a lab for testing automatic failover for SQL Server

I have a 2 node WSFC (SQL-CLUSTER-TEST-01) with the nodes

- SQL-TEST-01
- SQL-TEST-02

A listener SQL-HA-GRP-01

My initial testing is to just power off either of the nodes (virtual machines). It it failing correctly in one direction - SQL-TEST-01 to SQL-TEST-02. But when SQL-TEST-02 is the primary and I pull the power on it, the availability group goes into a permanent "resolving" state which I can only resolve by powering on SQL-TEST-02.

When I check the logs or try to view the properties of the availability group it says the quorum was lost.

What am I missing?

Comment: What quorum mode is configured for the WSFC?

Comment: Can you add an answer if this was resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to get this sorted out?

If not , try the following:

- Go to the `Failover Cluster Manager` ( `cluadmin.msc` from `Run`).
- Expand the Cluster name ( Expand meaning click on the `+` sign ).
- Expand `Services and Applications`. You should now see your Availability Group listed there.
- <kbd>R-click</kbd> on that and go to `Properties`.
- In the `General` Tab you should see `Preferred Owners`.

Since you've mentioned this to be a lab environment, play around with the options ( by selecting both or alternating selection of preferred owners ) and see where that gets you. Also the tab next to `General` would specify if you need it to fail back. Post back with results.

Comment: Also confirm your quorum voting is set up correctly.